# Pytorch torch.linalg.svd returning U and V^T, which are not orthogonal

Tags: vector, pytorch, svd, orthogonal, numerical-stability

Using U,S, VT = torch.linalg.svd(M), the matrix 'M' is large, so I am getting the matrices U and VT as non orthogonal. When I compute torch.norm(torch.mm(matrix, matrix.t()) - identity_matrix)) its 0.004 and also when I print M.M^T, the diagonal entries are not 1, rather 0.2 or 0.4 and non diagonals are not 0, but 0.0023. IS there a way to get SVD with orthogonal U and V^T ?
But the singular values i.e. diagonal elements of S are nera to 1 only.

```
matrix = torch.randn(4096, 4096) 
u, s, vh = torch.linalg.svd(matrix) 
matrix = torch.mm(u, vh)
print('norm ||WTW - I||: ',torch.norm(torch.mm(matrix, matrix.t()) - torch.eye(matrix.shape[0]))) 
print(matrix)
```

I have done some numerical analysis, and it seems Pytorch's linalg_svd is not returning orthogonal u and vh. Can others verify this behaviour is with others too or I am doing something wrong?

Matlab:
I tried inbuilt svd decomposition in matlab, and there `norm(u*transpose(u) - eye(4096))`, there its 1E-13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you expect `matrix @ matrix.T` to be close to `I`?

[`SVD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) is a *decomposition* of the input matrix `matrix`. It does not alter it, it only produces three matrices `u`, `s` and `vh` s.t. `matrix = u @ s @ vh`. The special thing about `SVD` is that the matrices `u`, `s` and `vh` are not arbitrary, but unique: `u` and `v` are orthogonal, and `s` is diagonal.

What you should actually expect is:

```py
matrix = torch.randn(4096, 4096) 
u, s, vh = torch.linalg.svd(matrix)

print(f'||uuT - I|| = {torch.norm(u@u.t() - torch.eye(u.shape[0]))}')
print(f'||vvT - I|| = {torch.norm(vh.t()@vh - torch.eye(vh.shape[0]))}')
```

Note that due to numeric issues the difference `||uuT -I||` is not likely to be exactly zero, but some small number depending on the dimensions of your matrix (the larger the matrix -- the greater the error), and the precision of the `dtype` you used: `float32` (aka `single`) will likely to result with larger error compared to `float64` (aka `double`).

---

PS,  the operator `@` stands for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Sorry for pasting error in code. I meant matrix = torch.mm(u, vh)  to be orthogonal

Comment: @BhartenduKumar please edit your question to correct the typo.

Comment: @BhartenduKumar the norm of `||uuT-I||` is not exactly zero, due to numerical issues, but it should be very close to `I`.

Comment: You should use [`isclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isclose.html) to check

Comment: Also, I checked u and Vh, they too are not orthogonal. Like torch.norm(torch.mm(u, u.t()) - identity_matrix)) = 0.003 and  torch.norm(torch.mm(vh, vh.t()) - identity_matrix)) = 0.004

Comment: I tried isclose , for False as return value

Comment: @BhartenduKumar total error of `0.004` for a 4096x4096 matrix is not that big.

Comment: I tried SVD decomposition in Matlab, and that was near to 1E-13 @Shai

Comment: @BhartenduKumar were you using `float32` matrices in Matlab as well? The default precision in Matlab is `float64` which is likely to result with more numerically accurate results.

Comment: If you cast `matrix` to `float64` (`.double()`), you'll get errors in the order of `1e-13`-`1e-12` like in Matlab. Trying Matlab with `float32` (`single`) gives errors of about `1e-5`-`1e-4`.

Comment: @BhartenduKumar BTW, the errors I'm getting with pytorch float32 are `0.0003` which is x10 smaller than what you get - check your code.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense and helped greatly. Could you please update your answer with this type conversion line to make it answer what actually I was looking for? Thanks for looking in